# What will happen to GETH node once Ethereum 2.0 releases?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have a full GETH node running and looks like Ethereum 2.0 is about to release. My question is:

- Will I need to do tweak anything in my node once Ethereum 2.0 releases?
- Will my GETH full node be able to use Mainnet for transactions in Ethereum 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the phase 0 of Eth2 is about to release. And that also will only launch a public common testnet, nothing more. So there is no real hurry with anything.

In any case when the real Eth2.0 launches (after a year or two) you probably have to decide yourself whether you want to continue mining 1.0 chain (which will be active at least for some time) or consider starting as a validator in 2.0 chain where the rules are completely different.

In any case there is no way for your node to "accidentally" end up as a validator in Eth2.0.

For a developer the changes are probably not very big. Some semantics will possibly change a bit (possibly stuff like `block.timestamp` or so) but mostly I think there shouldn't be big differences.

Comment: Isnt the phase 1 release of beacon chain part of the mainnet? Also I am not a miner but just a developer. What changes would I need to do to use Ethereum 2.0 in GETH once it releases?

Comment: beacon chain release is phase 0. And its release is not going to mainnet yet (as there is no mainnet for 2.0 yet). Edited answer to add info for developer

Comment: So, all the phases(0,1,1.5,2) will be release on test net. And then only on mainnet??

Comment: Yes, first they are tested in testnets. For example the phase0 has been in half-private testnets for half a year now and is supposed to be released to a public common testnet today